# FastAPI get user ID from API key

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

In fastAPI one can simply write a security dependency at the router level and secure an entire part of the URLs.

```
router.include_router(
    my_router,
    prefix="/mypath",
    dependencies=[Depends(auth.oauth2_scheme)]
)
```

This avoids repeating a lot of code.

The only problem is that I would like to protect a part of URLs with a router level dependency that checks the validity of the user token and retrieve the user id for that token.

The only way I found, is to add another dependency to all the functions, but this leads to repeating the code that I just saved.

Long story short, is there a way to add the dependency at the router level, retrieve and return the user id, and pass the returned value to the handling function? Something like

**router.py**

```
router.include_router(
        my_router,
        prefix="/mypath",
        dependencies=[user_id = Depends(auth.oauth2_scheme)]
    )
```

**my_router.py**

```
my_router = APIRouter()

@my_router.get("/my_path")
async def get_my_path(**kwargs):
    user_id = kwargs["user_id"]
    # Do stuff with the user_id
    return {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the user is authenticated in the dependency function add the user_id to `request.state`, then on your route you can access it from the request object.

```py
async def oauth2_scheme(request: Request):
    request.state.user_id = "foo"

my_router  = APIRouter()

@my_router .get("/")
async def hello(request: Request):
    print(request.state.user_id)

app.include_router(
    my_router,
    dependencies=[Depends(oauth2_scheme)]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, did not think about accessing directly the request.

Comment: It is worth to add that route dependencies and normal dependencies have two different scopes and can be duplicated (one checks the auth key, the other gets the data) with no performance losses thanks to caching, as discussed in https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/424
Don't know why I didn't find it at the time of asking the question...

Answer (score 1):

**You can follow the below steps to solve your problem**

- First change on router.py file(because I can add prefixes and dependencies on my_router.py)

```
    router.include_router(my_router)
```

- Second on change on my_router.py

```
  my_router = APIRouter(prefix="/mypath",dependencies=[user_id:=Depends(auth.oauth2_scheme))

 @my_router.get("/my_path")
 async def get_my_path(userId=user_id):
       return userId
```